# Making an entire grid of objects fall toward the bottom of the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a grid of raindrops fall to the bottom and disappear once it passes the bottom of the screen. What is happening with the current code is one row will fall to the bottom and disappear. The whole grid will appear no problem if I want them to move horizontally. I don't think the code issue is in rainy_day.py, I believe the issue is in raindrop.py. I've posted both below.

## raindrop.py:

```
import pygame 
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class RainDrop(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single raindrop in the fleet."""

    def __init__(self, rain_game):
        """Initialize the raindrop and set its starting position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = rain_game.screen
        self.raindrop_settings = rain_game.raindrop_settings

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/raindrop.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def check_edges(self):
        """Return True if rain drop reaches the bottom of the screen screen."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.top >= screen_rect.bottom:
            return True

    def update(self):
        """Move the raindrop down."""
        self.y += self.raindrop_settings.rain_speed
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

## rainy_day.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from raindrop_settings import Settings
from raindrop import RainDrop

class RainyDay:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.raindrop_settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
                (self.raindrop_settings.screen_width, self.raindrop_settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Rainy Day")

        self.raindrops = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self._create_fleet()

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_raindrops()            
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    def _update_raindrops(self):
        """
        Check if the fleet is at an edge,
          then update the positions of all raindrops in the fleet.
        """
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.raindrops.update()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Create the fleet of raindrops."""
        raindrop = RainDrop(self)
        raindrop_width, raindrop_height = raindrop.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.raindrop_settings.screen_width - (2 * raindrop_width)
        number_raindrops_x = available_space_x // (2 * raindrop_width)

        available_space_y = (self.raindrop_settings.screen_height -
                             (3 * raindrop_height) - raindrop_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * raindrop_height)

        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for raindrop_number in range(number_raindrops_x):
                self._create_raindrop(raindrop_number, row_number)

    def _create_raindrop(self, raindrop_number, row_number):
        """Create a raindrop and place it in the row."""
        raindrop = RainDrop(self)
        raindrop_width, raindrop_height = raindrop.rect.size
        raindrop.x = raindrop_width + 2 * raindrop_width * raindrop_number
        raindrop.rect.x = raindrop.x
        raindrop.rect.y = raindrop.rect.height + 2 * raindrop.rect.height * row_number
        self.raindrops.add(raindrop)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        """Respond appropriately if the raindrops have reached the edge."""
        for raindrop in self.raindrops.sprites():
            if raindrop.check_edges():
                self.raindrops.remove(raindrop)

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.raindrop_settings.bg_color)
        self.raindrops.draw(self.screen)     
        pygame.display.flip()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rainday = RainyDay() 
    rainday.run_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign position to `raindrop.y` instead of `raindrop.rect.y` (or to both)

```
raindrop.y = raindrop.rect.height + 2 * raindrop.rect.height * row_number
raindrop.rect.y = raindrop.y
```

because later you use `self.y` to change `self.rect.y` when you move `raindrop`

---

You assign different values to `self.rect.y` but all objects have the same `self.y` so later all rows are moved to the same row and it draws only one row.